# How show backButton when we navigate for tabs?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-router-flux

I'm developing an app in ReactNative with 3 tabs and one of this tabs have a nested tabs not visible. I using react-native-router-flux to do that. I have 2 issues:

1. When I try to put the name of the first tab that have the nested tabs, I only can see the name of the parent tab (image attached).
2. It is possible hide/show the back button when I navigate between the nested tabs?

**My Router.js**

```
<Router sceneStyle={ styles.router } backAndroidHandler={ onBackAndroid } hideNavBar>
  <Scene key="root">
     <Scene
          key="customer"
          title={ "APPNAME" }
          // type={ 'reset' }
          headerMode='none'
          tabBarPosition='top'
          tabs
          hideNavBar={false}
          wrap={false}
          showLabel
          // swipeEnabled={ true }
          // lazy={ true }
          tabBarStyle={ styles.tabBarStyle }
          titleStyle={ styles.titleStyle }
          navigationBarStyle={ styles.navigationBarStyle }
          backButtonTintColor={'#FFF'}
          renderRightButton={ renderNavBarRightMenu }
        >
          <Scene key="customerHome">
            <Scene key="scanQR" component={ HomeCustomerContainer } />
            <Scene key="vehicleDetail" component={ OrdersContainer } />
          </Scene>
          <Scene key="customerOrders" component={ ProfileContainer } hideNavBar/>
          <Scene key="customerProfile" component={ ProfileContainer } hideNavBar/>
        </Scene>

      </Scene>
    </Router>
```

When the users go from scanQR to vehicleDetail in the Router the back button don't appear. I need this behaviour because the users could go back when they want.

The behaviour must be: an user push the floating button, open the camera and scan a barcode. Then when barcode is read they get information from a server and show it in a new scene, but the back button don't appear.

What's wrong in my code?

Thanks!!

**Image**
[image]
**UPDATE:**
I found solution for the problem of the title:

> A Scene that is a direct child of Tabs and can use all props listed
>   above in Scene,

https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#tab-scene-child-scene-within-tabs

I still have the problem with show the back button when I open another scene :(

Comment: Create one with a button on press navigate.back()

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
onBackFunction()
{
  console.log("backkkkkkkkkk")
  Actions.sceneA()
}


<Scene key="root" >
          <Scene  key="sceneA" component={SceneA} />
          <Scene  key="sceneB" onBack={this.onBackFunction()} component={SceneB} />
</Scene>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Android Team, but I want to hide the back button on the parent scene ("customer") and show when I navigate to "vehicleDetail".